# How do I get a reference to a mapquest map from outside the script where it's defined?

Tags: javascript, mapquest

I'm maintaining some code that involves the mapquest map API. There's a javascript init() function which has this line:

```
map = new MQA.TileMap(document.getElementById('map'),6,{lat:34, lng:-118},'hyb');
```

which sets up the map in a  down the page with the id of 'map', as per the API.

My problem is that I want to be able to access this map from outside this function, but I can't seem to find anything in the mapquest API about getting the map object from the div it's contained in. Trying to call map-related methods on the result of document.getElementById("map") just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you would use the global variable `map` to reference it.

```
var map;
function setUp(){
    map = new MQA.TileMap(document.getElementById('map'),6,{lat:34, lng:-118},'hyb');
}

function doSomething(){
    if(!map) return;
    map.XXX();  //where XXX is the method you want to call
}
```

Comment: Bah, I really should know by now how scope in javascript works. Of course that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I actually created a global var with window.map. But whenever I try to getShapeCollection() it's empty. Even though there are POIs on the map. can you help me with that? I also can't wipe the old POIs on a new query with map.removeShapeCollection();